# Show that a weak-star closed subset of dual is proximinal.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, approximation-theory

I stumbled upon the following problem, which I am yet unable to solve.

Let X be a normed space and let $C \subset  X^*$  be a nonempty, $w^∗$ (weak-star) closed set.
Show that $C$  is proximinal, that is, for any given $x^* \in  X^*$, there exists $u \in C$  such that $ ||x^* - u ||  = d(x^*  , C)$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it. Let $x^* \in X^*$ and $d=d(x^*,C): = \inf \{ ||x^*- z|| \colon z \in C\}$. By the definition of infimum, for any $ n \in \mathbb N$, we have that $ B_{d+1/n}(x^*)\cap C:= \{  z \in C \colon || z-x^*|| \leq d+1/n \} \neq \emptyset$.
Let $$ A_n = B_{d+1/n} (x^*)\cap C , \ n \in \mathbb N.$$
The family $(A_n)_n $ consists of $w^*$-closed sets and it can easily be checked that it has the finite intersection property. Since  $\  B_{d+1}(x^*) \supset  A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots \ $   and $B_{d+1}(x^*)$ is $w^*$ compact  (Alaoglou's theorem), we must have that    $ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_{d+1/n}(x^*) \cap C \neq \emptyset $. It's  not hard to see  that  for any $z \in  \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_{d+1/n}(x^*) \cap C ,\ $  $||x^*-z||=d$.